# Getting file view statistics

Tags: php, file, statistics, count

I have a file that is being linked to from other sub websites.

```
http://site.com/file.img
```

The other websites would link to it as

website A:

```
<img src="http://site.com/file.img"></img>
```

website B:

```
<img src="http://site.com/file.img"></img>
```

How can I get statistics about the number of times each website called this file? 
Could these results be tampered? For example could website A fake being website B?

Answer (score 3):

Website A could indeed fake being B. The HTTP Referer (sic) is trivial to fake.

What you want is something like this...

#### .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

# Send all png, gif, jpeg, jpeg to image.php 
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)\.(png|gif|jpe?g)$ image.php?img=$1
```

#### PHP

```
<?php

if ( ! isset($_GET['img'])) {
    exit;
}

$img = $_GET['img'];

// Easily spoofed
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])
   AND $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] === 'http://example.com') {
   // This image appears to be requested by example.com
}

// Avoid directory traversal attacks and validate image extension
if ( ! preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+\.(gif|png|jpe?g)$/', $img)) {
   exit;
}

// Get image type
list(,,$type) = getimagesize($img);

// Send headers and echo file contents
header('Content-Type: ' . image_type_to_mime_type($type));
readfile($img);
```

If you don't want to match such a specific referrer string, you can use `parse_url()` to get the domain, and then compare that (or however you want to compare).

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution: use URL Rewriting to redirect accesses to your file to a script (e.g. a PHP) counting them and then returning the file.

Answer (score 1):

If you are checking by Referral variable, yes it can be faked.
But if you have luck that sites A and B are on different IP addresses you can access
web server logs and count access times / Ip addr